# How can I sort by numerical properties in org-agenda?

Tags: org-agenda

I have defined a property "SWAY", which can be numbers between 0 and 1000

```
* TODO Task 20                                                       :hukarz:
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-05-01 Fri]
:SWAY:     40
:END:

* TODO Task 3                                                        :hukarz:
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-07-01 Wed]
:SWAY:     3
:END:
```

I want an org-agenda view where it's sorted by SWAY

```
(defun my/org-agenda-sort-by-numerical-property (a b)
  (let* ((a-pos (get-text-property 0 'org-marker a))
         (b-pos (get-text-property 0 'org-marker b))
         (sway-a (org-entry-get a-pos "SWAY"))
         (sway-b (org-entry-get b-pos "SWAY")))
    (cond
     ((and sway-a sway-b) (if (< (string-to-number sway-a) (string-to-number sway-b) 1 -1)))
     ((and sway-a (not sway-b)) 1)
     ((and sway-b (not sway-a)) -1)
     (t nil))))

(setq list-todo-by-swayer
  `("ltz"
    "i.TODO o.sway"
    tags                   
    "+TODO=\"TODO\""
    (
     (org-agenda-overriding-columns-format "%TODO %4SWAY %30ITEM %20TAGS")
     (org-agenda-view-columns-initially t)
     (org-agenda-files '("~/agenda/test.org"))
     (org-agenda-cmp-user-defined 'my/org-agenda-sort-by-numerical-property)
     (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(user-defined-down))
     )
    ))

(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands list-todo-by-swayer)
```

This is what I'm getting now.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments if 1)
  (if (< (string-to-number sway-a) (string-to-number sway-b) 1 -1))
  (cond ((and sway-a sway-b) (if (< (string-to-number sway-a) (string-to-number sway-b) 1 -1))) ((and sway-a (not sway-b)) 1) ((and sway-b (not sway-a)) -1) (t nil))
  (let* ((a-pos (get-text-property 0 'org-marker a)) (b-pos (get-text-property 0 'org-marker b)) (sway-a (org-entry-get a-pos "SWAY")) (sway-b (org-entry-get b-pos "SWAY"))) (cond ((and sway-a sway-b) (if (< (string-to-number sway-a) (string-to-number sway-b) 1 -1))) ((and sway-a (not sway-b)) 1) ((and sway-b (not sway-a)) -1) (t nil)))
  my/org-agenda-sort-by-numerical-property(#("  test:       TODO Task 3 ..." 0 14 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 14 18 (org-heading t effort-minutes nil effort nil face org-todo fontified t org-category "test" tags ("hukarz") org-priority-highest 65 org-priority-lowest 69 time-of-day nil duration nil breadcrumbs nil txt #("TODO Task 3               ..." 0 4 ... 4 5 ... 5 11 ... 11 49 ...) ...) 18 19 (org-category "test" tags ("hukarz") org-priority-highest 65 org-priority-lowest 69 time-of-day nil duration nil breadcrumbs nil txt #("TODO Task 3               ..." 0 4 ... 4 5 ... 5 11 ... 11 49 ...) level " " time "" extra "" format (... ...) dotime nil ...) 19 25 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 25 63 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...)) #("  test:       TODO Task 20..." 0 14 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 14 18 (org-heading t effort-minutes nil effort nil face org-todo fontified t org-category "test" tags ("hukarz") org-priority-highest 65 org-priority-lowest 69 time-of-day nil duration nil breadcrumbs nil txt #("TODO Task 20              ..." 0 4 ... 4 5 ... 5 12 ... 12 49 ...) ...) 18 19 (org-category "test" tags ("hukarz") org-priority-highest 65 org-priority-lowest 69 time-of-day nil duration nil breadcrumbs nil txt #("TODO Task 20              ..." 0 4 ... 4 5 ... 5 12 ... 12 49 ...) level " " time "" extra "" format (... ...) dotime nil ...) 19 26 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 26 63 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...)))
  #<subr org-entries-lessp>(#("  test:       TODO Task 3 ..." 0 14 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 14 18 (org-heading t effort-minutes nil effort nil face org-todo fontified t org-category "test" tags ("hukarz") org-priority-highest 65 org-priority-lowest 69 time-of-day nil duration nil breadcrumbs nil txt #("TODO Task 3               ..." 0 4 ... 4 5 ... 5 11 ... 11 49 ...) ...) 18 19 (org-category "test" tags ("hukarz") org-priority-highest 65 org-priority-lowest 69 time-of-day nil duration nil breadcrumbs nil txt #("TODO Task 3               ..." 0 4 ... 4 5 ... 5 11 ... 11 49 ...) level " " time "" extra "" format (... ...) dotime nil ...) 19 25 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 25 63 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...)) #("  test:       TODO Task 20..." 0 14 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 14 18 (org-heading t effort-minutes nil effort nil face org-todo fontified t org-category "test" tags ("hukarz") org-priority-highest 65 org-priority-lowest 69 time-of-day nil duration nil breadcrumbs nil txt #("TODO Task 20              ..." 0 4 ... 4 5 ... 5 12 ... 12 49 ...) ...) 18 19 (org-category "test" tags ("hukarz") org-priority-highest 65 org-priority-lowest 69 time-of-day nil duration nil breadcrumbs nil txt #("TODO Task 20              ..." 0 4 ... 4 5 ... 5 12 ... 12 49 ...) level " " time "" extra "" format (... ...) dotime nil ...) 19 26 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 26 63 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...)))
  org-agenda-finalize-entries((#("  test:       TODO Task 20..." 0 14 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 14 18 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 18 19 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 19 26 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 26 63 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 1 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...)) #("  test:       TODO Task 3 ..." 0 14 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 14 18 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 18 19 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 19 25 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...) 25 63 (type "tagsmatch" priority 2000 ts-date nil todo-state "TODO" org-hd-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> org-marker #<marker (moves after insertion) at 139 in test.org> help-echo "mouse-2 or RET jump to Org..." org-complex-heading-regexp "^\\(\\*+\\)\\(?: +\\(DO\\(?:ING\\..." org-todo-regexp "\\(DO\\(?:ING\\|NE\\)\\|TODO\\)" org-not-done-regexp "\\(DOING\\|TODO\\)" mouse-face highlight undone-face default done-face org-agenda-done ...))) tags)
  org-tags-view(nil "+TODO=\"TODO\"")
  #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x12aa3b9ff46c0014>)()
  funcall(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x12aa3b9ff46c0014>))
  (let ((org-agenda-overriding-columns-format '"%TODO %4SWAY %30ITEM %20TAGS") (org-agenda-view-columns-initially 't) (org-agenda-files '("~/agenda/test.org")) (org-agenda-cmp-user-defined 'my/org-agenda-sort-by-numerical-property) (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(user-defined-down))) (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x12aa3b9ff46c0014>)))
  eval((let ((org-agenda-overriding-columns-format '"%TODO %4SWAY %30ITEM %20TAGS") (org-agenda-view-columns-initially 't) (org-agenda-files '("~/agenda/test.org")) (org-agenda-cmp-user-defined 'my/org-agenda-sort-by-numerical-property) (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(user-defined-down))) (funcall '#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x12aa3b9ff46c0014>))))
  org-agenda(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-agenda nil)
  command-execute(org-agenda)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were sort of close but there's a lot of little details that aren't necessarily obvious; it took me a little while to track them all down.

The first major key point is that you need to use `org-agenda-cmp-user-defined`; the help file for this indicates that you can now use `user-defined-up` as a sorting strategy, so I went looking for a variable that would look like those two words and found `org-agenda-sorting-strategy`. The documentation for that told me what that was supposed to look like. Here I just killed all other sorting bits for the sake of example.

Second, your sorting function needs to handle all user cases properly, which means, what do you do when one is nil, what do you do when both is nil?

And third, the API for the sorting function is to return 1, -1, or nil, as per the documentation.

This latest error was happening because of a misplaced parens around the if statement; the error indicates `if` receives only one argument, which doesn't make sense, it needs two (and an optional third). If you look at the documentation for if you'll see the first argument is a conditional clause and the second is what to do if the clause is true. The parens never closed the conditional clause. This is now fixed.

Also fixed the direction of the comparison so it properly sorts in ascending order.

```lisp
(defun my/org-agenda-sort-by-numerical-property (a b)
  (let* ((a-pos (get-text-property 0 'org-marker a))
         (b-pos (get-text-property 0 'org-marker b))
         (sway-a (org-entry-get a-pos "SWAY"))
         (sway-b (org-entry-get b-pos "SWAY")))
    (cond
     ((and sway-a sway-b) (if (> (string-to-number sway-a) (string-to-number sway-b)) 1 -1))
     ((and sway-a (not sway-b)) 1)
     ((and sway-b (not sway-a)) -1)
     (t nil))))


(let ((org-agenda-files '("/tmp/foo.org"))
      (org-agenda-custom-commands '(("li"
                                     "o.sway"
                                     tags
                                     "+hukarz"
                                     (
                                      (org-agenda-overriding-columns-format "%TODO %SWAY %100ITEM 100%TAGS")
                                      (org-agenda-view-columns-initially t)
                                      (org-agenda-cmp-user-defined 'my/org-agenda-sort-by-numerical-property)
                                      (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(user-defined-up))
                                      )
                                     ))))
  (org-agenda nil "li"))
```